# Random numbers array in html

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am experimenting with JavaScript and I want to display a string of generated random numbers that are stored in an array in the html.

I currently am only able to display one value in the bottom section with .toString()

What I want is for each time generate is pressed the new value is added to the array and the full array printed as a list underneath.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body bgcolor="#000000">

    <font size="30" color="orange">Hex Value :-  <strong><p align="center"><font size="80" color="orange"><span id="first"></span></p></strong>

    <p align="center"><button onclick="incremente()">Generate</button></p>

    <font size="3" color="green">Values generated this session:-  <strong><p align="center"><font size="40" color="green"><span id="second"></span></p></strong>

        <script>
            function incremente() {
                var CHARS = new Array();
                rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (17 - 0)) + 0;
                randy = Math.round(rand);

                $outChar = randy;
                $first = $outChar;
                var place1=document.getElementById('first');
                place1.innerHTML=$first;

                CHARS.push($first);
                $second = CHARS.toString();

                for (i=0;i<CHARS.length;i++)
                {
                    var place2=document.getElementById('second');
                    place2.innerHTML=$second;
                }
            }
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might be better off starting with some tutorials.

Comment: It's a good practice not to begin a variable in javascript with `$` to avoid confusion with variable in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the array above the function such that it becomes global.

Check the code.

```html
<body bgcolor="#000000">
<font size="30" color="orange">Hex Value :-  <strong><p align="center"><font size="80" color="orange"><span id="first"></span></p></strong>
    <p align="center"><button onclick="incremente()">Generate</button></p>


    <font size="3" color="green">Values generated this session:-  <strong><p align="center"><font size="40" color="green"><span id="second"></span></p></strong>

        <script>
           var CHARS = new Array();//moved above the function such that it becomes global.
            function incremente() {
                
                rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (17 - 0)) + 0;
                randy = Math.round(rand);

                $outChar = randy;
                $first = $outChar;
                var place1=document.getElementById('first');
                place1.innerHTML=$first;





                    CHARS.push($first);
                    $second = CHARS.toString();



                for (i=0;i<CHARS.length;i++)
                {
                    var place2=document.getElementById('second');
                    place2.innerHTML=$second;
                }

            }
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YU1V704wlX026wH86Xui?p=preview) for you to play with your code in js

Comment: You can use the replace command  do something like this $second.replace(/,/g, " "); updated my fiddle http://plnkr.co/edit/YU1V704wlX026wH86Xui?p=preview

Comment: i cant seem to get the replace command to react to the string. would it be best implemented in the array loop?

Comment: i added this to handle the commas but it isnt right. 
                    `CHARS.push($first);
                    $inter = CHARS.toString();
                    $inter.replace(/,/g, " ");
                    $second = $inter;`

Comment: `//this will make teh array into string                   $second = CHARS.toString();`
to this string do the replace it will work.